# Booting Xen guests with UEFI

Tags: virtual-machine, uefi, xen

Now that UEFI is gaining widespread adoption, is Xen able to boot guests using an emulated UEFI? If so, can secure boot be used for these guests?

Comment: [This may help](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/OVMF), but I can't verify this atm.

Comment: Yes; it's possible; what has your research shown though; you have to enable it in the configuration file for the VM